# No such module 'DJIWidget' when trying to integrate DJI video feed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dji-sdk

I have been trying to integrate the `DJIWidget` library into my `Xcode` project to display a live video feed from a drone, but I have been unable to get `Xcode` to find the `DJIWidget` module.

I tried downloading the DJI [iOS-FPVDemo-Swift](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/iOS-FPVDemo-Swift) project and running `pod install`, but it has the exact same problem, where Xcode cannot find the `DJIWidget` module.

Is this an issue with the way Cocoapods is installing it?

I am using `Xcode 10.1.`

Comment: When you use Cocoapods you need to open the Xcode workspace, not the project. Is it possible you are opening the Xcode project?

Comment: @idz I am opening the workspace after running `pod install`, so I'm afraid it's not this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember DJIWidget has an issu with the last version of Cocoapods 1.6.0. Could you degragde your Cocoapods to 1.5.3 and try again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Downgrading to 1.5.3 seems to have fixed it!

Comment: Ugh, downgrading to 1.5.3 now gives me "no DJISDK module"